# Optimize H2 SQL like query: where 'where' clause is not followed by column name

Tags: sql, optimization, h2

I have this sql like query running on H2 database.

```
select columnA from table 
where :param like columnB || '%' 
order by char_length(columnB) desc 
limit '1' offset '0'
```

The problem is, this query runs full table scan despite columnA and columnB are indexed.
I believe this is because the where clause is not followed by a column name but parameter.
Using explain analyze for query below, I can see indexing is used to select data but it is not what I want.

```
select columnA from table 
where columnB like :param || '%' 
order by char_length(columnB) desc 
limit '1' offset '0' 
-- Note: This query is not an option.
```

Performance is very critical in my application and full table scan is not affordable.
How can I optimize this query to have better performance?

Comment: The problem is that you are using calculations on the column: `columnB || '%'`

Comment: See this similar problem and a wonderful answer: [Algorithm for finding the longest prefix](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43415/algorithm-for-finding-the-longest-prefix). It's for Postgres but the idea is just excellent.

Comment: Thanks. That is one good information. However, the "Simple Solution" is still doing full-table scan and is way too slow for me. "text_pattern_ops" looks good but I'm not sure H2 database has this kind of operator classes. Any idea? The other solutions are just assuming the prefixes have a limited number of characters which is not in my case.